# Cygwin and "failed to run aclocal: No such file or directory"

Tags: cygwin, autoconf

I'm trying to test our Autotools stuff on Cygwin. When I open a prompt:

```
$ autoreconf --install --force
Can't exec "aclocal": No such file or directory at /usr/share/autoconf/Autom4te/FileUtils.pm line 326.
autoreconf-2.69: failed to run aclocal: No such file or directory
```

I re-ran the Cygwin package manager and verified `autoconf`, `automake` and `libtool` were installed. There is no package `aclocal` to install.

Searching is not returning useful hits in the context of Cygwin.

What is the problem, and how do I fix it?

Comment: brew install automake,libtool

Comment: I had this error for a different package manager and the solution was to install `automake`.

Answer (score 30):

So it looks like it is not enough to install Autoconf 2.69, Automake 1.15 and Libtool. There are other packages that need to be installed, but Cygwin does not install them.

First, I needed the package called *automake: wrapper for multiple versions of Automake*. Second, I needed the package called *libtool: generic library support script*.

The package called *autoconf: wrapper for multiple versions of Autoconf* was already installed, so it did not need to be installed.

If the Autools package needs them, then it should probably install them when users select packages like Autoconf 2.69 and Automake 1.15.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Anyone reading this. Pay attention to the difference between Auotmake 1.15 and "automake: wrapper for multiple versions of Automake"

Comment: Is it then recommended to just install the generic `Automake` rather than the versioned one? Does it pull out all versions? I haven't tried the various permutations

Comment: What a mess. To compile anything takes way too long.

Answer (score 0):

It just cannot find  aclocal

- Find the aclocal

```
$ which aclocal-1.15
/usr/bin/aclocal-1.15
```

- Then create the soft link, then it works

```
$ ln -s /usr/bin/aclocal-1.15 /usr/bin/aclocal
```

Comment: If the error " error: automake failed with exit status: 1" , just  "ln -s /usr/bin/automake-1.15 /usr/bin/automake" as well